# Perl: Signals and Threads. How to kill thread with qx() inside

Tags: multithreading, perl, signals

i have a script, that parse log and find errors and warnings.
And i want to use user-friendly interpretation of this log.
For this reason, i use `notepad`.
Here is code:

```
use v5.16;
use strict;
use warnings;

use Win32::Clipboard;
use threads;
use utf8;

my $kp = Win32::Clipboard->new();

my $output = shift || "out_log.txt";

#my ($input, $output)=@ARGV;
#open my $ih, "<", $input or die "can't open input file with log\n";

open my $oh, ">", $output or die "can't open output file with log\n";
my @alls=split /\n/,$kp->Get();

for my $k(0..$#alls){
    $_ = $alls[$k];
    if(/^ERR.+|^WARN.+/){
        print {$oh} qq(at position $k --> ).$_."\n";
        }
    }
my $thread = 
threads->create(sub{
                $SIG{INT}=sub{die"All good\n";};
                qx(notepad $output);
            }
        );

print qq(type 'y' for quit);
do{
    print "want to quit?\n>" ;
    chomp;
    do{
        say "I will kill this thread";
        $thread->kill('INT') if defined($thread);       
        say "and delete output";
        unlink $output;
        exit(0);
        }if (m/y/);
    }while(<>);
```

It falls down, when i trying to kill thread which run notepad.
How to do this, using signals and threads? Is it possible?
And your ideas about solution, please.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't working because your `SIGINT` never gets passed to `notepad`. So it never gets closed. (And that handler - probably never gets processed).

You need to approach this differently. Look at `Win32::Process` for some examples of how to spawn/kill a notepad process.

```
my $ProcessObj;
    Win32::Process::Create( $ProcessObj,
        "C:\\Windows\\system32\\notepad.exe",
        "notepad", 0, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, "." )
        or die $!;
```

And then you can use

```
$ProcessObj -> Kill(1);
```

I'd suggest using `Thread::Semaphore` or some sort of shared variable to decide if you want to kill your notepad.